# как сделать проверку на повторяющееся число из массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, она выводит рандомное число из массива. Как сделать проверку на выводило ли это число раньше?

Comment: убивать число в массиве - не будет

Comment: А зачем добавлять уже существующее число?

Comment: Массив можно модифицировать?

Answer (score 2):

2 варианта - записывать использованные числа в массив и потом проверять, есть ли число там, например, так:

```
[7,8,6,2].includes(8)
```

Или, если использованные числа больше нигде не нужны, то просто удалять их из массива

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать метод reduce совместно с includes, чтобы отсеять повторяющиеся значения

```js
var arr = new Array(10).fill(0).map(i => ~~(Math.random() * 10));

console.log(
      'Начальный: [' + arr.join(', ') + 
      '] => без дублей: [' 
      + arr.reduce((r, c) => r.includes(c) ? r : (r.push(c), r), []).join(', ') 
      + ']');
```